# How to Get Recently viewed Products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, database

i want to get all data from magento core table 
table name is

> report_viewed_product_index

i searched on stakeexchange and found some solution but havn't for success

```
class Wbtab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        $collection = $this->_recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();

        print_r($collection->load()->getData());
        exit();

    }
}
```

Comment: get recent view product collection ????

Comment: yesss actually that what i want but i am gettingnull when  tried that code

Comment: try this print_r($collection->getData());

Comment: tried that already still getting same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
class Wbtab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }  
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        $collection = $this->_recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
             $info = $data->getData();
             print_r($info);      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. its working

Comment: wel come..happy coding...:)

Comment: can i add filters to collection like product_id filter or date filter

Comment: let me check....

Comment: another thing when i logout user i returns null

Comment: this collection is not return how many time is product reviewed ?

Answer (score 0):

try this ...... definatly work

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
} 
public function getMostRecentlyViewed()
{
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$recentlyViewedClass = \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Viewed::class;
$recentlyViewedProductCollection = $objectManager->create($recentlyViewedClass)->getCollection();
$recentlyViewedProductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->setPageSize(5) // load 10 products
                                ->load();

if($recentlyViewedProductCollection->getSize() > 0 )   {
 
    $product['message'] = "";
    foreach($recentlyViewedProductCollection as $item) {
        $data[]= $item->getData();
        $product['data'] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($product);
    die;
}
```

}
}